# How we define $M^s$ for $s\in (0,1)$ and $M$ a positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $F$. Let $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)^+$ (i.e. $\langle Mx\;, \;x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in F$).

- The square root of $M$ is defined to be the unique operator $N$ such that
  $$N^2=M.$$
- In this case we write $N=M^{1/2}$

> Let $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)^+$ and $s\in (0,1)$ be a real number. How we define $M^s$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $M$ is normal, you can use the [Continuous Functional Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus): the C$^*$-algebra $C^*(M)$, generated by $M$ is isomorphic to $C(\sigma(M))$. As $\sigma(M)\subset[0,\infty)$, the function $f(t)=t^s$ is continuous on $\sigma(M)$, and so by pulling back $f$ with the isomorphism you get $f(M)=M^s$.

If you know the Spectral Theorem, since $M$ is selfadjoint you can define
$$
M^s=\int_{\sigma(M)}\lambda^s\,dE(\lambda).
$$

This last approach is nice in that it works on a Banach algebra, so it is irrelevant if $M$ is normal and/or positive. If $M$ is invertible and its spectrum does not surround $0$, then $g(z)=z^s$ (defined as $g(z)=e^{s\log z}$ is analytic. Then you can use the Riesz Functional Calculus to get an explicit expression: 
$$
M^s=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma z^s\,(zI-M)^{-1}\,dz,
$$
where $\gamma$ is any curve that contains $\sigma(M)$ and does not contain $0$.

The important fact is that all three definitions agree wherever they make sense, so there is no way to say that one is better than the others.

Comment: Is the following formula not correct  $$M^s=\int _{\sigma(M)}\lambda^s dE_{\lambda}$$? Thank you.

Comment: Of course. But if you know the Spectral Theorem I fail to see what your question is.

Comment: My question is what is the first definition of $M^s$? Is it as you write or with spectral theorem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wouldn't know what "first" means there. You can define it either way.

Comment: I think that the integral representation in not a definition. I think that $r^{1/2}$ is defined to be the unique solution of $x^2=r$.

Comment: What about $r^{\pi}$?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know. There is a small mistake in your answer in the integral presentation.

Comment: Thanks, corrected. That's the thing, your argument works for power 1/2, and with a little work for rational powers. But it makes no sense for arbitrary powers. For a positive real number, the usual thing is to define $r^s$ to be $\exp(s\,\log r)$. An important thing I forgot to mention in the answer is the important fact that all three definitions agree where they make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.